Llama-3-70B with pipeline cannot generate new tokens (texts)
I have sucessfully downloaded Llama-3-70B, and when I want to test its "text-generation" ability, it always outputs my prompt and no other more texts.
Here is my demo code (copied from huggingface and did a little bit modifications like temperature and top_p)
import transformers
import torch

model_id = "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-70B-Instruct"

pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model_id,
    model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": torch.bfloat16},
    device_map="auto",
)

messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant designed to output JSON."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Who are you?"}
]

prompt_text = "\n".join([msg["content"] for msg in messages])

terminators = [
    pipeline.tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    pipeline.tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids("<|eot_id|>")
]

outputs = pipeline(
    prompt_text,
    max_new_tokens=500,
    eos_token_id=terminators,
    do_sample=True,
    temperature=1.0,
    top_p=1.0,
)
print(outputs)

The output is here
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 30/30 [00:01<00:00, 28.45it/s]
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:128001 for open-end generation.
[{'generated_text': 'You are a helpful assistant designed to output JSON.\nWho are you?'}]

I expect it can generate something new, not only my input prompt.
